# memory mismatch between pandas dataframe and csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a big excel file similar to following blog.

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/

The post is about converting object type columns to category type. This reduces the memory usage of the dataframe.

I am working on a excel file of 88 MB. After following the steps mentioned in the code, I am able to reduce the size of df to 28 MB.
The problem is when I write it to csv file, the file size 193 MB, which is more than the original csv file.

Question: What is causing the memory mismatch and how to overcome?
Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('games_log.csv')
df.info(memory_usage='deep')


def mem_usage(pandas_obj):
    if isinstance(pandas_obj,pd.DataFrame):
        usage_b = pandas_obj.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
    else: # we assume if not a df it's a series
        usage_b = pandas_obj.memory_usage(deep=True)
    usage_mb = usage_b / 1024 ** 2 # convert bytes to megabytes
    return "{:03.2f} MB".format(usage_mb)

#This part converts the columns of object type to category type
converted_obj = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns:
    num_unique_values = len(df[col].unique())
    num_total_values = len(df[col])
    if num_unique_values / num_total_values < 0.5:
        converted_obj.loc[:,col] = df[col].astype('category')
    else:
        converted_obj.loc[:,col] = df[col]


print(mem_usage(converted_obj)) 
print(mem_usage(df))

converted_obj.to_csv('compressed_file.csv',index=False)
```

The last line writes the dataframe to csv but the file size is huge.

Comment: what's `'games_log.csv'` can you give an example that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: games_log.csv is a file used in the project. It's available here https://data.world/dataquest/mlb-game-logs difficult to reproduce with sample data as the problem is dealing with huge data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Given the condition `if num_unique_values / num_total_values < 0.5:`, all columns are `True`
2. Based upon what you have displayed, all of the code can be replaced with the following:

## New Code:

```
game_logs.csv = 132.901MB
df = pd.read_csv('game_logs.csv', dtype='category')
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 171907 entries, 0 to 171906
Columns: 161 entries, date to acquisition_info
dtypes: category(161)
memory usage: 52.8 MB

df.to_csv('game_logs_new.csv', index=False)
game_logs_new.csv = 133.069MB
```

1. In the case of your code, you reduced the amount of memory used, but when you save the file, it's larger.  **In this case, the transformation you applied may have added data to the `DataFrame` in some way.**
2. What I think you're are trying to do is reduce the actual size of the file with `DataFrame` transforms and that isn't going to happen (unless you delete a lot of data).
3. Different `dtype` are stored in memory differently; some are more efficient than others, but when you save it back to the `csv`, you're still just storing a bunch of text; **`dtype` from the `DataFrame` is not maintained in `csv`**